# How to re-init the AlpineJS component after Livewire re-renders?

Tags: laravel, initialization, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have an alert component that I hide using AlpineJS but I want it to be visible again after Livewire re-renders.

**Showing the alert using Livewire component**

```php
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <x-success-alert :message="Session::get('success')" />
@endif
```

**AlpineJS component**

```php
<div x-data="{show: true}">
    <div x-show="show">
        <span>{{ $message }}</span>
        <button @click="show = false">&times;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't, a component is initialized only once.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to force Livewire to add that element in the dom again by adding `wire:key` to a random value.

```php
<div wire:key="{{ rand() }}">
    <div x-data="{show: true}">
        <div x-show="show">
            <span>{{ $message }}</span>
            <button @click="show = false">&times;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With that way, Livewire will destroy the old dom element and add the new one which re-init the Alpine component.

Comment: This was helpful but I changed it up a bit.  I used md5 and json_encode to check to see if the data had actually changed: wire:key="{{ md5(json_encode($message)) }}"

Comment: This is the best answer imho

Comment: I used this and it caused another element to be duplicated after each component re-init. any other idea?

Comment: wire:key doesn't effect other elements, the issue might not be with that.

Comment: I totally forgot to add the key to the loop items. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone else, I have found that if an alpine component within a Livewire component is removed from the dom, it is not loaded correctly if reinstated *if the `x-data` directive is applied to the outermost element.

So, for example, just wrap the `<x-success-alert>` component in an additional div:

```html
<div>
    <div x-data="{show: true}">
        <div x-show="show">
            <span>{{ $message }}</span>
            <button @click="show = false">&times;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I couldn't see how is this relevant to the question asked... thanks for the insight. BTW Have you noticed the same behavior with `wire:key` too?